# Need a tag for LibreSSL

Tags: support, tags

OpenBSD just forked OpenSSL. They called it LibreSSL. http://www.openbsdfoundation.org/.

Would it be possible to have a tag 'LibreSSL' created for it on stackoverflow.com?

OpenBSD is legendary for its security and OpenSSL has room for improvement at times, so I expect the projects to diverge to the point they are not similar in some areas. The OpenBSD folks have already gutted a lot of cruft, and more modifications are coming. For example, SSLv2 support has been removed, as has all the custom-but-not-quite-right reimplementations like `OPENSSL_printf`, `BUF_strlcpy`, and `BUF_strlcat`.

OpenBSD does not plan on upstream patches because OpenSSL usually does not act on patches for bug fixes and features. For example, see the years old bug [OpenSSL fails if used from multiple threads and with SSL_MODE_RELEASE_BUFFERS](http://rt.openssl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=2167&user=guest&pass=guest) in their tracker. And OpenSSL does not accept patches from people in the United States. See, for example, [Re: Could openssl foundation give itself rules not to accept money from intelligence agencies?](https://www.mail-archive.com/openssl-users@openssl.org/msg73596.html).

Comment: The MSE FAQ explaining tag creation: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146949/when-is-tag-creation-appropriate-and-how-does-it-work

Comment: Interesting. Are there any LibreSSL-specific questions yet? It's not possible to create a tag without applying it to a question.

Comment: You have more than enough rep to create tags.  If you want to create a tag, create a tag.

Comment: OT, but do they really not accept patches from US citizens? The post from Steve Marquess seems to refer specifically to commit access - presumably US citizens can still get their code reviewed and accepted (or, per your earlier point, languishing in the review queue / bug tracker) like every other non committer

Comment: @michel-slm - yes, they don't accept anything from folks in the US. They are worried about the US's export controls on cryptography, so the project avoids it all together. Even the servers are located in Europe to avoid the US. However, it does not explain why they won't accept patches for documentation. I've been submitting them for years, and I've never had one accepted. See, for example, [Documentation for PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC](https://rt.openssl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=3293&user=guest&pass=guest). They would not even accept a patch on spelling corrections in existing documentation.

Comment: @jww Wow, here's to hoping LibreSSL is managed better

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[You only need 1,500 rep to be able to create a new tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags), so if you see any questions that you think would benefit from the tag, then simply add it. Tags cannot exist<sup>*</sup> without being attached to questions.

If it turns out not to be useful - by it not getting added to any more questions - then it can and will be removed.

You don't have to get community agreement for this.

<sup>* There is a case where if a tag has a wiki, but it needs to have been created first</sup>